# short way to check (one liner) if a file exists or not

Tags: linux, shell

I'm looking for a very short way to check if a file exists or not. If the file exists `1` should be printed and if not `0` should be printed.

The below syntax doesn't print anything? Just an empty output

```
if [ -f /proc/$pid/stat ]; then echo '1' else echo '0' fi
```

Comment: You're missing the `;` after each `echo` statement.

Comment: You are missing several semicolons or newlines, so it's hard to say.

Comment: @chepner Not newlines since he wants it to be a one-liner.

Comment: If you type interactive, you should get a `>` prompt because you haven't finished the `if` statement.

Comment: You could just write `! [ -f /proc/$pid/stat ]; echo $?`.

Comment: ok, thanks.. now it works.. but can it be even more reduced? the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ -f file ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Answer (score 1):

added some ';'

```
if [ -f /proc/$pid/stat ]; then echo '1'; else echo '0'; fi
```